# Change connection string in Class Library Project

Tags: vb.net

In my earlier project I was able to change the connection string during the app settings loaded event and it was successfully.  When I try to do the same for a code library project, I am not getting the system.configuration.connectionstringsettings to work.  Could you please tell if there is a work around for this, or else it is always better to write the sql code instead of depending on the adapters etc.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Additional information:
Clients App is WPF with Vb.
Database is SQL Server 2008
Code Lib would only be on server, slq connectiona and data retrieving and saving actions are stored in classes in code lib only.
Code Lib would be used with WCF, wcf is used to share the classes only and classes have the data.
WCF is hosted as a windows service on server used by NET.TCP

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to system.configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LibraryName.My.MySettings.ConnectionString" connectionString="..." />
<connectionStrings>
```

Then from your library, check:

```
My.Settings.ConnectionString
```

Comment: Sorry @a programmer, that only for reading from the connection string and it would not allow me to write data into it. It is ready only.  Thank you.